# Why does t point to letter C?

Tags: c

I want to read my string backwards. I did that, but I don't understand how two parts of my code work.

```
char s1[] = "ABC";
printf("%s", s1);
size_t len = strlen(s1);
printf("\n%d", len);

char *t = s1 + len - 1;
printf("\n%s\n", t);

while (t>=s1)
{
    printf("%c", *t);
    t = t - 1;
}
```

- First: How does `t` point to letter C?
- Second: How is it possible to add variable `len` which holds integer with an array that holds literals? Is it because pointer t adds their addresses by using pointer arithmetic?

Comment: `printf("\n%d", len);` has undefined behavior. `%d` takes an `int`, not a `size_t`.

Comment: `ptr + n` is sort of like `&ptr[n]`

Comment: I don't see `t=C` anyware in the code.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, I think Jan means that the assignment to t, which is `char *t = s1 + len - 1` winds up pointing to the letter "C" because `char s1[] = "ABC"`.  so not literally `t = C` but more like `*t == 'C'`  or just "t points to a 'C'"

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor No. `%d` printf specifier takes an `int` argument. `%zu` printf specifier takes `size_t` argument. All arguments in the variadic argument list undertake integer promotions (ie. `char` is converted to `int` - [understand integer promotions](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules)).

Comment: Better to use `char *t = s1 + len; while (t>s1) ...`  (no + 1, > vs >=).  (Drop the `printf("\n%s\n", t);`) Else output is a problem when `len == 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
char s1[] = "ABC";
```

looks like

```
 0x100   0x101  0x102   0x103 . . . .Assume 0x100 is base address of s1
 --------------------------------
|   A   |   B   |   C   |   \0   |
 --------------------------------
s1
```

Here `s1` which is char array, points to base address `0x100`(let's assume).

> I want to read my string reversely ?

For this you need someone to point to `0x102` location i.e last element of an array, for that

```
size_t len = strlen(s1); /* finding length of array s1 i.e it returns 3 here */
char *t = s1 + len - 1; /* (0x100 + 3*1) - 1 i.e char pointer t points to 0x102 */
```

above two lines of code is written. Now it looks like

```
 0x100   0x101  0x102   0x103 . . . . 
 --------------------------------
|   A   |   B   |   C   |   \0   |
 --------------------------------
s1                  t <-- t points here
```

Now when you do `*t` it prints the char value at `t` location i.e value at `0x102` i.e it prints `C`, in the next iteration you need to print the char one position back, so for that you are doing `t = t - 1;`.

**Note :** Here

```
char *t = s1 + len - 1;
```

`s1` is **char pointer** and `len` is an **integer variable**, so when you are doing **pointer arithmetic** it will automatically increment by the size of data being pointed by pointer. For e.g

```
char *t = s1 + len;
```

evaluated as

```
t = 0x100 + 3*sizeof(*s1); ==> 0x100 + 3*1  ==> 0x103
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Needs a little bit of an explanation that pointer arithmetic *knows the size of the item being pointed to* and adding an integer n to a pointer p in code, creates a pointer that is n * sizeof(*p) bytes after the address of p.  like if you have an `int* ptrToInt` and the ptrToInt is 0x100 then `ptrToInt +n` has the address of 0x100 + sizeof(int) * n;

Comment: Yes @Wyck this `n * sizeof(*p)` is correct. For example in OP case I wrote in comments `(0x100 + 3*1)` where `3` is `n` and `sizeof(*p)` is `1`.

Comment: you are welcome on stack overflow family @JanKlimaszewski

Comment: nit: `Here s1 which is char array, points to base address` is not correct.  s1 is an array.  It doesn't point to anything.  When s1 is passed to a function or used in pointer arithmetic, it is treated as a pointer to the first element.  But is is not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`char s1[] = "ABC";`

`s1` is an array of 4 characters `char[4]` with values `{'A','B','C','\0'}`

`size_t len = strlen(s1);`

`s1` "decays" (read: is automagically converted) from an array of type to a pointer to type. So `s1` decays from an array of 4 characters into a pointer to the first character of the array.

The `strlen` counts the number of bytes before encountering the null byte delimiter `'\0'`. Starting from `'A'` we can count `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'` - that's `len = 3`.

Pointers in C are normal integers (ok, on most architectures). You can add to them and substract to them, and use `uintptr_t` to convert them to an integer. But adding to them without a cast will use "pointer arithmetics", that means that `(int*)5 + 2` is to the value equal to `5 + 2 * sizeof(int)`.

`char *t = s1 + len - 1;`

`s1` decays to the pointer to the first character inside the `s1` array, that's `'A'`. We add `+ (len = 3)`, that means that `s1 + 3` points to the byte holding `'\0'` inside the `s1 = (char[4]){'A','B','C','\0'}` array. Then we subtract `- 1`, so `t` will now point to a byte holding the character `'C'` inside the `s1` array.

```
while (t >= s1) {
    ... *t ...
    t = t - 1;
}
```

Start: `s1` points to `'A'`. `t` points to `'C'`.
while: `t` is greater then `s1`. By two. `t - s1 = 2`, ie. `s1 + 2 = t`
loop: `*t` is equal to `'C'`.
decrement: `t--`, so now `t` will point to `'B'`.
while: `t` is greater then `s1`. By onw.
loop: `*t` is equal to `'B'`.
decrement: Then `t--`, so now `t` will point to `'A'`.
while: Now `t` is equal to then `s1`. Both point to the first character of the array.
loop: `*t` is equal to `'B'`.
decrement: Then `t--`, so now `t` will point to an unknown location before the array. As pointers
 (on most architectures) are simple integers, you can decrement and increment them as normal variables.
while: `t` is now lower then `s1`. Loop terminates.

Notes:

- `printf("\n%d", len);` is undefined behavior and spawns [nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Use `printf("\n%zu", len);` to print a `size_t` variable.
- you can print pointer value by using the `%p` specifier and casting to void `printf("%p", (void*)t)`
- `t = s1 - 1`. Assigning a pointer to one element before an array is undefined behavior in C. That happens in the end condition of the loop when `t = t - 1`. Change to `do { .. } while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the language C arrays are a bit strange. At array-of-x can degrade in to a pointer-to-x, very easily. For example if passing to another routine, or as in your case when adding to it. So you are correct it is pointer arithmetic. (In pointer arithmetic you can add pointers and integers, to get pointers.)